# What does “ventordici” mean?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, numbers

I was reading an article today that has the following heading:

> Huawei P30 e P30 Pro svelati: ventordici fotocamere, con tanto di zoom 10x (foto)

So what does ventordici means? Just a way to say a ridiculously big number?

[image]

Article: https://www.androidworld.it/2019/02/28/huawei-p30-pro-leaked-615265/

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @Charo Grazie Charo! Benvenuta anche a te ;)

Comment: Watch out for [_duemilacredici_](http://nonciclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Duemilacredici) too!

Comment: @VincenzoOliva is there a new `-dici` trend?

Comment: @marcanuy: They're both wordplays: just like _ventordici_ is the combination of _venti_ ("twenty") and _quattordici_ ("fourteen"), _duemilacredici_ combines _duemilatredici_ (2013) and _credici_ (literally "believe it", idiomatically "don't count on it") into a fake, unreachable year. E.g. you may see the sentence _Half-Life 3 uscirà nel duemilacredici!_ , which amounts to _Half-Life 3 probabilmente non uscirà mai_ ("Half-Life 3 will likely never come out").

Comment: @VincenzoOliva thanks for the explanation, it was really helpful! You can add it as an answer too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can read in [this semi-serious blog article](http://nonciclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Ventordici) *ventordici* is an imaginary number with some strange properties.

> Ventordici: numero immaginifico fondamentale del campo complessato.

It is an informal way to describe a huge quantity that cannot be determined, like, for example *zillions*.

Another similar word we use in Italian is *fantastilione* that can be translated to *bazillion*.

As suggested by @VincenzoOliva, another word used with similar meaning is *millemila*.